# How to insert item in advanced recyclerview library

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Using android-advancedrecyclerview library, I want to use two adapters and a RecyclerView to achieve the following:

List header(first list)

- List item 0
- List item 1

**Add new list item**

List header(Second list)

- List item 0
- List item 2
- List item 3

**Add new list item**

I have decided to go with the ComposedAdapter that includes my 2 adapters.
My datasets for the adapters are at the Activity witch is where I also add new objects to the datasets.

Now, I am not sure how to handle item insertions. On what instance should I call
notifyItemInserted() and with what position?

This question is specific to android-advancedrecyclerview library.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried reset the RecycleView's adapter with the new content?

Make your adapter able to receive a content list and create a method that returns a new adapter (in this case a `ComposedAdapter`). Then set this method to your `recyclerView.setAdapter()` always you need update your data. This should work.